# Personalization conditions switching doesn`t work in Experience Editor

Tags: experience-editor, personalization

We are on 9.1.0, Initial Release

We personalize one particular rendering on page item. There are some different conditions that have different datasource item for this rendering.

[image: personalize rendering]

Personalization works good on website - datasource is changed according to conditions. But when we try to switch condition in Experience Editor - nothing happens. Datasource does not changed. There are no errors in log files and no errors in browser console.

[image: switch conditions]

Can anyone help to find what is wrong? Sitecore version is 9.1.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is an issue for Sitecore XP 9.1.0 (Initial Release). It is not reproducible in the Sitecore 9.0.x and pre-release version of Sitecore 9.2.

If you need a hotfix for Sitecore 9.1, you can request the fix from Sitecore Support. Public reference number is `312777`.

Comment: Thank you! Will do it.